# Web-scraping with Python 3 BeautifulSoup library

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Playing with web-scraping in Python 3. I m trying to web-scrape the following HTML page using the BeautifulSoup library in Python 3.

```html
<div class="container">
  <div item-id="1" class="container1 item details">
    <div class="item-name">
      <div class="item-business-name">
        <h3>My Business #1</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item-location">
      <div class="item-address">
        <p>My Address #1</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item-contact">
      <div class="item-email">
        <p>My Email #1</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div item-id="2" class="container2 item details">
    <div class="item-name">
      <div class="item-business-name">
        <h3>My Business #2</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item-location">
      <div class="item-address">
        <p>My Address #2</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item-contact">
      <div class="item-email">
        <p>My Email #2</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As the naming pattern of the required container(e.g. div item-id="1" class="container1 item details") changes for each item, I would appreciate a piece of advice on how to scrape item-business-name, item-address, item-contact for all items. There are 100 items on the page; hence, the last container is div item-id="100" class="container100 item details"

What is the best way to get all the items in the list at the "container 1-100" level, and after that I know how to get each item :) 
I was thinking of something like:

```html
n = 0
while n < 101
      item = soup.find_all(class_=f"container{n} item details")
      n = n + 1
      print(item)
```

Unfortunately, it does not give me the required list.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use any number in `id` or class names. Just use `zip()` function to tie all information for the contact together

Variable `txt` contains HTML string from your question:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

out = []
for name, address, email in zip(soup.select('.item-business-name'),
                                soup.select('.item-address'),
                                soup.select('.item-email')):
    out.append([name.get_text(strip=True), address.get_text(strip=True), email.get_text(strip=True)])


# pretty print all rows:
for no, row in enumerate(out, 1):
    print('{}.'.format(no), ('{:<20}'*3).format(*row))
```

Prints:

```
1. My Business #1      My Address #1       My Email #1         
2. My Business #2      My Address #2       My Email #2
```